# A good example of implementing 'fashionable' large input text boxes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

A good example of implementing 'fashionable' large input text boxes like those found on [google](http://google.co.uk) and [tumblr](http://tumblr.com)?

On tumblr how do they use manage to get the input to flow backwards from where the cursor is in the box - on the final input box for URL.

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS:

```
input.FancyText {
    background: url(something) no-repeat;
    border: none;
    text-align: right;
}
```

You can see Tumblr's CSS using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com).

Comment: but can you make the search box 'fat' like tumblrs?

Comment: needs to be thick - i want a text box with girth

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just do like this:

```
input { padding: 10px; font-size: 26px; }
```

and it will make the input elements "fatter".

Answer (score 1):

```
input.fat
{
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 28px;
}
```

Comment: Incorrect spelling and no semi colons - please fix or I'm sure you'll be downvoted.

Comment: Grammar nazi! No need to be harsh. The idea counts.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't meant to be harsh. That's why I *didn't* downvote. But grammar and syntax are two different things. You can generally infer the meaning from bad grammar, but a computer can't do much with misspelled syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As SLaks suggested, you can use CSS to control the appearance of the input text boxes. For example, you could use firebug to discover that the CSS tumblr uses looks like this:

```
background-color:#F9F8E4; /* when in focus */
background:url("/images/input_bg.png") repeat-x scroll left top #F7FCFF;
border:1px solid #97B5D2;
color:#25313C;
font-family:Georgia,Times,"Times New Roman",serif;
font-size:28px; /* This probably makes it "fat" as you want */
width:480px;
font:13px 'Lucida Grande',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
margin:0;
outline:0 none;
padding:7px;
```

These are the active styles (which are spread across several different rules). Additionally, the comments are mine.

Try setting the font-size property to make the input area "fat"
Try setting the text-align:right property to make the input "flow to the right" as in the URL field.